# A way to migrate Windows Scheduler tasks from 2003 to 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

Does anyone know of a method to migrate from the .job format to the .xml format that 2008 server uses?

I have dozens of working scheduled tasks, and I want to migrate them to a new 2008 server.

Answer (score 2):

I know we normally frown on answers that are just links, but I don't see how else to post this: There's a [powershell script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-migrate-e4e5ea20) on the Microsoft site that might help you

The script is based on the discussion on a Microsoft staff member's blog [here](http://www.digitalforensics.be/blog/?p=205).